# deconvolution of exp($x^2$)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, signal-processing, computational-mathematics, image-processing

I would like to know whether we can get the  function of type exp($x^2$) by convoluting any functions. That is which function convolution gives exp($x^2$). Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you accidentally miss the negative sign, i.e. $\exp(-x^2)$? Try to convolve $\exp(-x^2)$ with itself.

Comment: $f(x)=e^{x^2}$ and $g(x)=e^{-x^2}$ yield $C(f,g) ~=~ \displaystyle\int_0^tf(\tau)~g(t-\tau)~d\tau ~=~ \dfrac{e^{t^2}-e^{-t^2}}{2t}$

Comment: no,I mean exp(x^2) only ,I would like to know whether any function when convoluted with itself or any other function will give exp (x^2) .whether there exits any method to find this ,I mean de convolution

Comment: one more thing ,as I am new to this I like to know how to put equations and symbols here ,like you did ..f(x)=exp(x^2).when I copied from word its not coming right .will you help me ..

Comment: See [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for a tutorial on writing mathematics with MathJax.